# If I have a correct reputation but still get "voting corrected" and I lose my reputation

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, voting, upvotes

I have some reputation on stack overflow account. I have my big team and followers in my office. They all are believe in my questions and answers. They also find many positive questions and answers. Sometime they used to up-vote my questions or answers. I never request them to up-vote it. They are doing themselves.

Few days later, Suddenly, I lose my 410 reputation with message "**Voting corrected**".

I have not earned my false reputation. What should I do to get back my reputation?

Please help to get back my reputation as all know which is very important to someones profile.

Thanks

Comment: "as all know which is very important to someones profile" lol no

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: By "flowers" in your office, Do you mean "followers"?

Comment: @BhargavRao What do you rather have? Flowers or followers?

Comment: I'm scared of flowers, @rene.

Comment: Please send flowers in lieu of followers.

Comment: "Me and my flowers will take over the state" sounds beautiful, though. Almost benign. Even when followed by "... and install a totalitarian regime"

Answer (score 17):

If they indeed are votes from your colleagues, as you say, then they have been cast in a way that is indistinguishable from voting for you as a person, rather than for your content. They might mean well, you may not have asked for the votes, but unfortunately the system can't make this judgment. And you probably know as well that even those with less than stellar intentions would use a similar excuse when caught.

Long story short, you're not going to get that reputation back. If you want to prevent that from happening in the future, ask your colleagues not to vote on your content if they don't come by it organically. That is, don't have them seek you or your profile out to see if you have written another brilliant contribution.

Rather, have them use Stack Overflow as they normally would. If they occasionally look for an answer and come upon a great one you've written, they can vote for the great answer. Or for great questions of course. Chances are very small that any problems would occur this way.

So to get back your reputation, keep on providing your best contributions, and wait for organic votes from the community to happen. And on a sobering note, while you may like your Stack Overflow reputation, in the grand scheme of things it doesn't mean all that much, besides some of the privileges you'll earn on the site.

Answer (score 2):

> Few days later, Suddenly, I lose my 410 reputation with message
>   "Voting corrected".

That means the votes were coming from your physical location probably. You say these were your colleagues, but it may also have just been you. You may also have asked them to vote for your posts. Point is, the votes seem to have focused extraordinarily on *you* as a person, not your content, or at least the behavior is undistinguishable from that. That's why they were reversed.

Also

> I have not earned my false reputation. What should I do to get back my
>   reputation?

Nothing. You can't get it back. A CM decided the votes were illegitimate (I assume it wasn't the script since the script runs daily it took a couple days for you) so they are. Just move on and tell your colleagues to not just upvote your stuff because it's you anymore.

> Please help to get back my reputation as all know which is very
>   important to someones profile.

Eh, not really. It's more of a *very* vague indicator as to how much you've contributed and how much the community trusts you. Unless you want to get serious with moderation, you don't need a lot of it, really.

And if you do, certainly you'll understand that curbing behavior like this is necessary for the site to keep itself fair and keep abusers and serial voters out.